# How to deobfuscate AS3 source code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to de-obfuscate AS3? With de-obfuscation I mean making it compilable again. At this moment I lost some source code and only have the Flash file left. The problem I now face is that the compiler is not able to compile it as the class names contain illegal characters.

I could start manually naming all classes again however I'm not even certain if the de-compiler worked.

To compile the SWF again I use flash develop and the FlashSDK.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the code was obfuscated to begin with. If it was simply obfuscated by changing class/variable/function names, then you could use an IDE such as FlashDevelop which allows you to Refactor->Rename by right clicking the instance name which would rename it across the entire project. Or just do a simple find/replace using a text editor.

Knowing how the code was obfuscated is the most important thing though. Whichever program you used to obfuscate is probably going to provide you with the most information.

I would suggest, however, doing the bare minimum by removing all illegal characters first to see if it will compile.

Comment: The problem here I have about 400 classes which all contain a illegal character(-). Manually changing this would take ages.

Comment: You could write a script that would iterate through the folder and remove the characters using a blacklist of illegal characters. How easy this is to do in AS3 I don't know.